# How to make div expand only from bottom down

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I have a div in a modal below. The problem I'm having is when I click on Add Row, this creates another div with a row and expands both top and bottom. The div then goes off the screen after a couple of rows added. Please see screenshots. 
Note: the query-row element is an angular directive, so that's why you don't see the template for that (which includes the actual fields and add row button). But that's irrelevant in this case.

HTML

```
<div class="ng-modal ng-cloak" ng-show="true">
    <div class="ng-modal-overlay">
        <div class="ng-modal-close">
            <div class="ng-modal-close-x">CLOSE</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ng-modal-dialog">
            <div class="ng-modal-dialog-content">
                <div class="document-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="document-content">
                        <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
                            <query-row rows="rows" remove-row="removeRow(row)" add-row="addRow()"></query-row>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <button ng-click="submit()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            <button ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-info">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ng-modal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.ng-modal-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #282828;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.ng-modal-dialog {
    z-index: 10000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 164px;
    left: 53%;
    width: 800px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:#FFF;

}
.ng-modal-dialog-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

.ng-modal-dialog-input {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 36px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    outline: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-weight:700;

}

.ng-modal-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 28px;

}
.ng-modal-close-x {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
}
.ng-modal-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 200%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
}
```

Plunker Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/RFNsrC

First screenshot is just with one row. 
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I798.png)
The second screenshot is 3 rows added, and you can see how the modal goes off the screen on the top. I want it to remain fixed on top and grow only towards to the bottom [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66mFc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a codepen, The problem is where you are trying create the new row, it's above not below, try putting in a table. http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/buCHf

```
  <a href="#" class="button" ng-click="addRow()">Add Row {{counter}}</a>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
  <th width="200">Some Header</th>
</tr>
 </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="rowContent in rows">
      <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

And to set the css of the .ng-modal-dialog as follows:

```
height:900px;
overflow-x: auto;
```

Let me know if that works :)

Comment: So, in my code, basically put my query-row directive into a table? I tried that but it didn't work, same result :(

Comment: Ok the issue is fixed. But I just set the height and enabled overflow-x:auto and with a bit of margin-top.  now you can scroll down the results. http://plnkr.co/edit/3YSP2uSVneXF8lshJMKS?p=info

Comment: @user3092075 Let me know if that's ok. :)

Comment: @user3092075 Here i've added padding too so it fixes in to the modal nicely. http://plnkr.co/edit/3YSP2uSVneXF8lshJMKS?p=preview

Comment: Great, that works! However, I just tried in laterst version of IE and the boxes look crushed together :(

Comment: Show me a screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102747/discussion-between-user3092075-and-about-leros).